# How to test spring batch job reading from FTP writing to DB

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there any way to test spring batch job, that read file from ftp, parse it to domain model and write to DB. I guess it will be like this - put some file to classpath, than test reader going to read it and finally i check the database that data was stored

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it will be like this - put some file to classpath, than test reader going to read it and finally i check the database that data was stored

Yes, that is a good way to design an integration test for the batch job you described.